# How to use 2 switch statement to get a return data from both switch

Tags: php

I have some question on the switch statement.

I want to get value from both switch statement.

```
$status = $bill->status;
$capsules = '';

switch($status){
    case Bill::STATUS_CREATED:
        $capsules .= "<div class = \"ui grey tiny label\">Created</div>";
        break;
    case Bill::STATUS_SENT:
        $capsules .= "<div class = \"ui blue tiny label\">Sent</div>";
        break;
    case Bill::STATUS_CANCELLED:
        $capsules .= "<div class = \"ui red tiny label\">Cancelled</div>";
        break;
    default;
        $capsules .= "";

}

switch ($status->Biil::getPaymentStatus()){
    case 'paid':
        $capsules .= "<div class=\"ui green tiny label\">Paid</div>";
        break;
    case 'partially':
        $capsules .= "<div class=\"ui brown tiny label\">Partially Paid</div>";
        break;
    default:
        $capsules .= "";
}

return $capsules;
```

how I get data from both switch statement using one return value.?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: If you mean you want the HTML from them as 2 separate units? Well first of all you can only return one "thing" one variable.  So a good choice here is a variable that can hold several things, We call that an Array. Then if you overwrite you values, or in this case concatinate them you'll have one string not 2.  So you could do them in the array as well as we just said it can store multiple things. Which is really convent as that is what we need to return what we want to return...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can only get value from the first switch statement. while I want both to show the value.

Comment: Do you want value separately?

Comment: Are you sure that your second `switch` statement has logic which is matching the input?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I try the same. but it does not show the result I want. the expected output should be 'sent' and 'paid' which both outputs get from both switch.

Comment: Give the value of default in second switch to check.

Comment: @SundarBan yes. I want the value separately.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Bill::getPaymentStatus()`, not `Biil::getPaymentStatus()`?

Comment: `I try the same. but it does not show the result I want. the expected output should be 'sent' and 'paid' which both outputs get from both switch.` - that's a whole diffrent issue, it's best to keep questions to one problem. That said, ikely it has to do with your input data, etc.  Which there is no way for us to tell, unless you provide it.  Not to mention I don't know what this is `Bill::STATUS_CREATED` and in your other switch you use strings for what looks like the same thing? Bill status vs Payment status.  Use constants if you have them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure. but I want to get the value from the other model by fetching it.

Comment: Thank u all. I have correct the wrong in my code. the reason I couldn't get both values simply changed Bill:getPaymentStatus to $bill->getPaymentStatus. thanks for spent valuable time for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using array to store the value separately.

```
    $capsules = [];
    switch ($status) {
        case Bill::STATUS_CREATED:
            $capsules[]= "<div class = \"ui grey tiny label\">Created</div>";
            break;
        case Bill::STATUS_SENT:
            $capsules[]= "<div class = \"ui blue tiny label\">Sent</div>";
            break;
        case Bill::STATUS_CANCELLED:
            $capsules[]= "<div class = \"ui red tiny label\">Cancelled</div>";
            break;
        default:            // change ; to : here. 
            $capsules[] = "default value in first switch";

    }


    switch ($status->Bill::getPaymentStatus()) {
        case 'paid':
            $capsules[]= "<div class=\"ui green tiny label\">Paid</div>";
            break;
        case 'partially':
            $capsules[]= "<div class=\"ui brown tiny label\">Partially Paid</div>";
            break;
        default:
            $capsules[] = "default Value in Second switch.";
    }

    print_r($capsules);  // print the value separately.
```